# Django Query many to many field count miscalculation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am creating a Django Blog Website and I am stuck at one point finding the no of likes on a specific post. I have created a webpage where all the posts are displayed. Now the problem I am facing is the no of likes are getting calculated wrong.

Post Model ->

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)   
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    Tags = models.CharField(max_length = 255,null=True,blank=True)
    Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Likes = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='Post_likes')
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(to=User,blank=True,related_name="favourite")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Query in Views.py file to fetch all the posts ->

```
posts =  Post.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('images_set').annotate(Count('comments_post')).annotate(Count('Likes')).all()
```

Now when I see the `post.Likes__count` in template it shows wrong count of 6 for one specific post but when I use `post.likes.count()` it shows count of 3.

for other posts they both show same result. I am unable to find out why it is happening.
This is the result for that specific post ->

```
{'post_id': 22, 'user_id': 1, 'title': 'wkjdfh', 'description': 'kjwdfn', 'Tags': '.,smdf,m', 'category': <Category: Shoes>, 'userName': 'admin', 'images': <QuerySet [<Images: Images object (10)>, <Images: Images object (11)>, <Images: Images object (12)>, <Images: Images object (13)>]>, 'comments_count': 6, 'likesCount': 6, 'actualLikeCount': 3}
```

This is very strange that is happening and I know there would be a reason for this but I am unable to find out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Django docs:

> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries

link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Try using `.annotate(Count(...), distinct=True)`.

Comment: WOW. This just solved my problem. Appreciate it man. Thanks
and for anyone else who is looking for the complete query -> 
    

`posts =  Post.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('images_set').annotate(comments_Count = Count('comments_post',distinct=True)).annotate(Count('Likes',distinct=True)).all() `

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ".annotate(Count('Likes'))". To get the number of likes in the template you can do this:

```
{{post.Likes.count}}
```

Comment: But this will generate a new query for every post which I dont want. I want it to be calculated in a single DB query

Comment: Are you sure that this generate a new query? You don't have to iterate throw the likes items

Comment: Yes it generates a new query for each post. I am using debug toolbar to monitor the number of queries.

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware: it will produce an *N+1* problem: https://scoutapm.com/blog/django-and-the-n1-queries-problem since for each `post`, where you do this, it will perform a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE ...` query.